C# MongoDB driver - find documents where value exists anywhere in content
I have an ASP.NET Core 9.0 Web API written in C# which queries a MongoDB using the MongoDB driver (3.1). The MongoDB has a collection called Foo and is intended to contain data from a variety of sources.
It has the following schema:
_id: objectId,
sourceName: string,
content: document

The content field seldom has the same data structure for any two documents e.g.
_id: ObjectId('66c63a62a9fa7c172aea24f8')
sourceName: "Foo-1"
content: {opName: "Django", opId: 3, accounts: ["sample1", "joe@google.com"]}

_id: ObjectId('66c63a62a9fa7c172aea24f9')
sourceName: "Foo-2"
content: {magazine: "Foo for beginners", author: "Joe Blogs"}

The user requirement is the ability to find any documents that contain a term e.g. find all documents that contain the term "Joe". In the above I would want to match on first documents accounts array and the second documents author.
Within the Web API, I have a Search endpoint which is where I want to query the MongoDB and this is where this post comes in. I cannot find a way to query the content field to determine if it contains the search term. I do not care which key/property has the matching value I only care if there is an occurrence of the search term somewhere within content.
I have tried using the regex method:
// request.Term = "Joe"
// _foo = mongoDbService.Database?.GetCollection<Foo>("foo");

var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(request.Term), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var filter = Builders<Foo>.Filter.Regex(r => r.Content, new BsonRegularExpression(regex));

await _foo.Find(filter).ToListAsync()

But I never get any matches.
The C# class for Foo:
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Foo
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("sourceName")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("content")]
    public BsonDocument Content { get; set; }
}

So, how do I query the content field to determine if ANY key/property has a value starting with/ ending with/ containing my search term?

It's a somewhat odd requirement, don't you think?  What can you do with such a document once you have it, if you don't know what the fields are?
